# How to express with regular expression? How can I delete all of English word without English word + Korean word

Tags: python, python-re

I use Python and 're' pakege to regular expression.
the problem is how can I delete the all of English word without English word + Korean word

for example text = "There are BTS는 인기가 많다."

the output I want => "BTS는 인기가 많다."

```
import re
   text = "There are BTS는 인기가 많다."
   result = re.sub('[A-Za-z]', '',text)
   #는 인기가 많다.

   result = re.sub('[A-Za-z]+[가-힣] ','',text)
   #There are 인기가 많다.
```

As a result, I want to prevent deletion of English characters that contain Korean characters.

How can I do it? thank you for your help

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]+ ` Does this match only free standing English?

Comment: The only English + Korean word in the text is this 'BTS는' but in your expected ouput there are standalone Korean words with English + Korean word.